# Unable to add JButtons wrapped in JPanel into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, flowlayout

I am having a `JTable`, where the final column of the table is for adding 2 buttons. Below is the format of my `JTable`.

[image]

Below is my code

```
private class ViewLawyersDisplayData extends ComponentAdapter
     {
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) 
        {
            dbConnector = new DBHandler();
            dbConnector.makeConnection();

            ResultSet rs =  dbConnector.selectAllLawyerDetails();

            if(rs==null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The table is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        int id = rs.getInt("lawyer_id");
                        String name = rs.getString("Name");
                        String address = rs.getString("Address");
                        String email = rs.getString("Email");
                        String phone = rs.getString("Phone");

                        JButton update = new JButton("Update");
                        JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");

                        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
                        btnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                        btnPanel.add(update);
                        btnPanel.add(delete);

                        Object[]row = {id,name,address,email,phone,btnPanel};

                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) viewLawyersTable.getModel();
                        model.addRow(row);
                    }
                }
                catch(SQLException sqlE)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sqlE.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

However I am unable to add the buttons into the final columns. Instead of showing the buttons, it shows some error text in the column. Below is the error text it shows to me.

```
javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: See [Table Column Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add Swing components to a table because a table is not used to display actual components.

See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one solution that provides the renderer/editor for a button in a column of the table.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the **model** and the **view**. Note that the model is the **data** to be displayed. In the case of `id` it is an integer value and in the case of `name` it is a String. You also have several other strings in your model.

The output you see is not an error message. It is simply the result of calling `toString()` on your `JPanel` because you are treating it as part of the model rather than a displayable view.

Since your `JPanel` is supposed to display UI components, it is a **view**. You need to read more about JTable in order to learn how to customize the view in each column.

Comment: link [How to use Tables: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)